# How non-static is accessible in static context in this program?

Tags: c#-3.0

I am having confusion with the following code:

```
    class A
    {
     int x;
     static void F(B b) {
      b.x = 1;  /* Ok, 
I want to know how is this ok, in a static block how a non static 
instance variables are called because as I know that static block 
gets memory at compile time before execution of a single command 
while non static at run time and static method accessing a non static 
variable which is not created yet please elaborate me on this
*/    
     }
    }
    class B: A
    {
     static void F(B b) {
      b.x = 1;  // Error, x not accessible
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing gets memory at compile time. Static fields are indeed placed in the static block of memory when the type gets initialized. Call stacks for static methods are allocated at run time exactly like in case of instance methods.

Now, why static methods don't have access to the instance fields. Consider this:

```
class A {
    public int Value;

    static int GetValue() {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

There you have a class with an instance field and a static method. Now, somewhere else you try this:

```
var a1 = new A();
a1.Value = 5;

var a2 = new A();
a2.Value = 10;

int result = A.GetValue();
```

Now, if compiler allowed this, what value would the result get? 5 or 10 or something else? This just doesn't make sense, because static methods are declared for class as a whole and aren't aware of instances of this class. So in the code of static method you don't know how many (if any) instances of this class exist and can't access their instance fields.

Hope this makes a little sense.

Comment: when i run program having a instance  variable int i, and i ty to access it in the public static void main method then it throws an error that non static variables can not be accessed int he static context what is the reason and also let me know how the above is correct

Comment: I modified my answer a bit trying to answer your questions

Comment: that is what i am asking in the above code ....how in the class A b.x = 1;  /* Ok, is correct..just explain me this

Comment: That's correct because when you pass an instance as a parameter there's no ambiguity. The method knows what object in memory you want it to work with and can be sure that this objects exists, so there is no problem with that.

Comment: Try this link, it can help you out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691335

Answer (score 1):

Either you changed the code in question a bit or I  didn't read very carefully. Seems like it's completely different problem right now. The variable x is indeed not accessible for the class B because of its level of protection (default in C# is private). Class A can modify X because it's declared in class A and visible to its method. Class B can't do it (you must make x protected or public for that).

Comment: that is what i am trying to understand how a a private is accessible to sub class ..i found this code on net..

Comment: It's not, class B can not access A.x

Comment: it can not access because x is private i think?

Comment: but how class A have access to x, ow come when we create objet of b class which has got no x variable is accessible in static context of class A

Comment: That's how inheritance works. When you have an instance of B, it has all the fields of A and B combined, but only methods of class A can access private fields that belong to A, and so on.